# .htaccess rule precedence

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, operator-precedence

I have the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^app ?page=app [QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/([0-9]+) ?page=app&id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/([0-9]+)/edit ?page=edit&id=$1 [QSA]
```

My page prints the GET params. When I call /app, the following is printed:

```
Array ( [page] => app )
```

When I call /app/123 or /app/123/edit, the print remains the same. However, when I reverse the order of the commands, I get different results.

For /app/123/edit:

```
Array ( [page] => edit [id] => 123 )
```

For /app/123:

```
Array ( [page] => app [id] => 123 )
```

Why is that? Also, is there a way to change that, because it seems easier to progress through the commands in a top-to-bottom hierarchical order, rather than the reverse. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you'll have to use the "end of string" symbol `$` :

```
RewriteRule ^app$ ?page=app [QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/([0-9]+)$ ?page=app&id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/([0-9]+)/edit$ ?page=edit&id=$1 [QSA]
```

Otherwise, since your first exp matches all of your URL forms, it is always used, and the rule checks never make it to line 2.

Comment: One question though: how can I make it that this part /[0-9]+/ adds the ?id=$1 [QSA] part to all the pages below /app without me having to explicitly repeat that ?id=$1 expression on the subsequent expressions?

Comment: The second and third rules in the question should be getting used since the L flag is never specified. Not sure why they aren't, but what you have done here is just force one and only one rule to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really handy resource:

http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

The reason the second and third do not match is that the output of your first rule wipes out the initial URI.

The actual rules you want are:

```
RewriteRule ^(app/?.*) $1?page=app [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(app/([0-9]+)/?.*) $1?page=app&id=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(app/([0-9]+)/edit) $1?page=edit&id=$2 [QSA]
```

Testing these with app/123/edit on the test page aboves shows the rules all match and apply as:

```
#   Match?  Rule    Resulting URL
1   yes RewriteRule ^(app/?.*) $1?page=app [QSA]    app/123/edit?page=app
2   yes RewriteRule ^(app/([0-9]+)/?.*) $1?page=app&id=$2 [QSA] app/123/edit?page=app?page=app&id=123
3   yes RewriteRule ^(app/([0-9]+)/edit) $1?page=edit&id=$2 [QSA]   app/123/edit?page=edit&id=123
```

I don't think the tester is handling the QSA flag correctly. I should only have to specify the new key/value pair in each rule and not have to restate the prior one(s). QSA should merge them. Your real error in your rules were to not preserve the URI.